# what is the max sum in path of tree

Tags: c++, algorithm

https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/maximum-path-sum/1 
this is question from geeks for geeks. i wrote my ans. but it is giving wrong. what is problem with my logic?

```
int path(Node *root, int & max_sum)
{
  if(root==NULL)
    return 0;
  int l=path(root->left,max_sum);
  int r=path(root->right,max_sum);
  max_sum=max(max_sum,l+r+root->data);
  return max(l,r)+root->data;
}

int maxPathSum(Node *root) 
{
  int max_sum=INT_MIN;
  path(root,max_sum);
  return max_sum;
  // code here
}
```

Comment: Just an educated guess: `int l=path(root->left,max_sum);` alters `max_sum`; if you expect that `max_sum` in the second call `int r=path(root->right,max_sum);` receives the same value for  `max_sum`
 than the first call, then you are probably wrong.

Comment: please include a [mcve] in the quesiton. What is the code supposed to do? What is the input, output and expected output?

Answer (score 0):

The problem statement says

> Find the maximum possible sum from one leaf node to another.

So, when you do

```
 max_sum=max(max_sum,l+r+root->data);
```

You will need to check whether the `root` has both the children. *Otherwise, they won't be considered in the final answer*.

You also did

```
if(root==NULL)  return 0;
```

and

```
max(l,r)+root->data;
```

These both combined are overriding a single leaf node child whose value is negative since 0 is greater than any negative integer.

So overall your code should look like this:

```
int path(Node *root, int & max_sum)
{
  if(root==NULL) return 0;
  int l=path(root->left,max_sum);
  int r=path(root->right,max_sum);
  if(root->left != NULL && root->right != NULL){
      max_sum = max(max_sum,l + r + root->data);
  }

  if(root->left != NULL && root->right == NULL) return  l + root->data;
  if(root->right != NULL && root->left == NULL) return  r + root->data;
  return max(l,r) + root->data;
}

int maxPathSum(Node *root) 
{
  int max_sum=INT_MIN;
  path(root,max_sum);
  return max_sum;
}
```